# Add Rows to a DataTable Containing Columns With Expressions in Winforms with Bound Controls VB.NET or C#

Tags: winforms, data-binding, datagridview, datatable, 2-way-object-databinding

I might be going about this all wrong so I will first explain what I am trying to accomplish, then what I have in Code so far.

I have a Winform with a DataGridview that is bound to a datatable. The datatable after being loaded from the database has 2 columns [widthName], [thickName] added with expressions to related tables for each of those columns. Those two tables are tied to two drop downs [Basically Name Value pair]. The DataGridView is ReadOnly. 
I am trying to allow the user to update the datagridview with values supplied by a textbox, and the two drop down boxes. Which does work.

The problem comes when I try to Add a New Record. The record does appear in the datagridview as I see my value for the Name Column , the controls do not show the values - the TextBox should match the name field but does not, neither does the datagridview show the computed values. I am obviously doing something wrong.

Any help is appreciated - C# or VB NET is fine I can convert - just need help to figure this out.

My DataTable is structured like this.
Id (Int), Name (String), Width (Int), Thickness (Int), WidthName (String)[Added With Expression], ThickName (String) [Added With Expression]

My relevant Code and a picture is attached.

```
    Private Sub CreateRelations

        Dim relWidth As DataRelation = New DataRelation("WidthDimension", dtWidth.Columns("Id"), dtDimensions.Columns("Width"), False)

        Dim relthick As DataRelation = New DataRelation("ThicknessDimension", dtThickness.Columns("Id"), dtDimensions.Columns("Thickness"), False)

        DsDimensions.Relations.Add(relWidth)

        DsDimensions.Relations.Add(relthick)

        Dim dcWidth As DataColumn = New DataColumn("WidthName", Type.GetType("System.String"), "Parent(WidthDimension).Name")

        Dim dcThickness As DataColumn = New DataColumn("ThicknessName", Type.GetType("System.String"), "Parent(ThicknessDimension).Name")

        dtDimensions.Columns.Add(dcWidth)

        dtDimensions.Columns.Add(dcThickness)


    End Sub

    Private Sub AddDataBindings()

        Dim widthBinding As Binding = New Binding("SelectedValue", dgvDimension.DataSource, "Width", DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)

        Dim thickBinding As Binding = New Binding("SelectedValue", dgvDimension.DataSource, "Thickness", DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)

        Dim nameBinding As Binding = New Binding("Text", dgvDimension.DataSource, "Name", DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged)

        widthBinding.DataSourceNullValue = 0
        widthBinding.NullValue = 0

        thickBinding.DataSourceNullValue = 0
        thickBinding.NullValue = 0

        nameBinding.DataSourceNullValue = "[New Dimension]"
        nameBinding.NullValue = "[New Dimension]"

        cmbWidth.DataBindings.Clear()
        cmbWidth.DataBindings.Add(widthBinding)

        cmbThickness.DataBindings.Clear()
        cmbThickness.DataBindings.Add(thickBinding)

        txtName.DataBindings.Clear()
        txtName.DataBindings.Add(nameBinding)
   End Sub



   Private Sub btnNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNew.Click

    If Not dtDimensions Is Nothing Then

        Dim rowView As DataRow = dtDimensions.NewRow()

        rowView.BeginEdit()
        rowView("Name") = "[New Dimension]"
        rowView("Width") = 0
        rowView("WidthName") = TryCast(cmbWidth.Items(0), DataRowView).Row("Name")
        rowView("ThicknessName") = TryCast(cmbThickness.Items(0), DataRowView).Row("Name")
        rowView("Thickness") = 0
        rowView.EndEdit()

        dtDimensions.Rows.Add(rowView)

   End If

    BsDimensions.ResumeBinding()

    BsDimensions.MoveLast()

    'AddingNew = False

    BsDimensions.ResetItem(BsDimensions.Position)

   ' txtName.DataBindings.Item("Text").ReadValue() - does nto read a value liek it is bound to nothing!

  End Sub
```

[image: New Row is Added - Missing values for the computed columns and also Textbox is empty, dropdowns are not set.]

Below I attach what it looks like when it loads and what a new row should look like - of course the Name field will at first be what the Default value is [new Dimension].

[image: Image how it should look when a new row is added - Note the Controls have data that matches the row.]

**EDIT**  One thing that appears to be happening is that the Computed Column Expressions do not evaluate.

Comment: I did it using a simple test app and it worked properly. Since your code is not an MCVE it's hard to guess what the problem may be. But make sure your `DataGridView` is bound to the same object which you added the new row to it.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Yes my datatable is bound to the bindinsource which is bound to the DataGridview - the records show up in the dataTable, and the new record shows in the grid WITH the exception as shown in the image , the new row does not have the computed columns Width and thickness, the Textbox is empty (should say '[New Dimension]') The drop downs have no selected item either.

Comment: @RezaAghaei in your example - do you have Expressions on your coluimns and do those columns get updated when adding a new row. I am only pulling the related field value in to that column, cell.

Comment: Yes, my test is really simple. See the code [here](http://pastebin.com/wDRXHUL8).

Comment: It's expected that you post such MCVE. Then usually you can solve the problem yourself or if you couldn't you can narrow the area of problem and let other users reproduce the problem simply and help you.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Your example is not using a related table in the expression.  I will take your example and add my related table and see what it does.

Comment: Great! Write minimal code as much as possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124934/discussion-between-ken-and-reza-aghaei).

Comment: What was the result?

Comment: @RezaAghaei - I tried to put it into chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124934/discussion-between-ken-and-reza-aghaei 
[here the code pastebin.com/TjdPQrh1 ] I have two problems 1: The expression does not show until after I change the selected row, how to update the text using the textbox. I am currently using a special method onTextChanged to update the data source .

Answer (score 0):

Issue >> Appears that Computed Column Expression do not evaluate.

Following code takes care of it. Add it at the end of CreateRelations Method.

```
        DataColumn dcName = new DataColumn("Name", Type.GetType("System.String"), "ISNULL(WidthName + 'x' + ThicknessName, '[New Dimension]')");
        dtDimensions.Columns.Add(dcName);
```

And for nameBinding you need only following. Remove other code for nameBinding.

```
        Binding nameBinding = new Binding("Text", bs, "Name");
```

Since you have said "*Those two tables are tied to two drop downs [Basically Name Value pair]*.", I assume that you have appropriately set **DataSource**, **DisplayMember** and **ValueMember** properties for the two dropdowns; if not you need to set them inside AddDataBinding Method as well.

Comment: I used Reza's example and suggestion to do what I needed to do. However I am responding here to let you know - I already had the name field - there was no issue with it - see the first picture with the new row. The Dimensions were not showing up. I had to use bs.acceptchanges at the proper times as per rezas example. The binding.NullValue properties work just fine. Two mistakes I did find was in the AddNew method -  setting widthname and thicknessname  - this caused a problem with the calculation being made when bs.acceptchanges was called The relation handles this already.